# How to quickly thaw frozen goose?

Tags: sous-vide, thawing, goose

I have a 5kg goose, frozen at -18C. I guess that even at room temperature, it won't be ready in about 15h to cook. What are my options? How quickly would it thaw in cold water sousvide? Its packaged airtight. Or should I simply put it in the oven early and run it on very low temp for some extra hours?

Answer (score 3):

Set it into the largest pot you own (that it will fit in) and fill the pot with cold tap water. Set it in your sink or set the pot on top of towels on the counter (to collect the condensation from the sides of the pan). Leave the goose/poultry in the water, turning it occasionally so that it thaws more evenly. It should thaw in plenty of time to go into the oven on schedule.